# Same library linked against SSL works differently in C++ and CGo code (P-192 public key)

Tags: c, openssl, cgo, ecdsa

I have a C library that uses SSL to initialize public key from data contained in `.pem` file. Here's the code:

```
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct Context
{
    EC_KEY* m_public_key;
    ...

} ctx;

EC_KEY* loadPublicKey(const char* pk_data)
{
    BIO* key_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pk_data, strlen(pk_data));
    EC_KEY* to_return = PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(key_bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(key_bio);
    return to_return;
}

bool init_ctx(const char* pk_data)
{
    ctx.m_public_key = loadPublicKey(pk_data);
    fprintf(stderr, "[C] pkey ptr = %ld\n", (uintptr_t)ctx.m_public_key);
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return ctx.m_public_key;
}
```

I build it as static library by using CMake and ninja:

```
SET (TARGET_NAME ecdsacgo)

ADD_LIBRARY (${TARGET_NAME} STATIC
    ecdsa_cgo.c
    sha256_cgo.c
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${TARGET_NAME}
    OpenSSL::SSL
    OpenSSL::Crypto
)

install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} DESTINATION lib/${TARGET_NAME})
...
ninja ecdsacgo
```

Then i link and use it in go code like so:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I./src/lib/security/cgo
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L./cgo_lib -l:libecdsacgo.a
// #include "ecdsa_cgo.h"
// #include <stdlib.h> // for C.free
import "C"
...
pkData, err := os.ReadFile(pubKeyPath)
cKey := C.CString(pkData)
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cKey))    
ok := C.init_ctx(cKey)
```

The problem i face is that when i call this code on P-192 public key data, `init_ctx` returns false, and output is

```
[C] pkey ptr = 0
140235868161952:error:100AE081:lib(16):func(174):reason(129):ec_curve.c:424:
140235868161952:error:100D7010:lib(16):func(215):reason(16):ec_ameth.c:202:
140235868161952:error:0B07707D:lib(11):func(119):reason(125):x_pubkey.c:154:
140235868161952:error:0906700D:lib(9):func(103):reason(13):pem_oth.c:83:
```

The description for those errors is

```
$ openssl errstr 0x100AE081
error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
$ openssl errstr 0x100D7010
error:100D7010:elliptic curve routines:ECKEY_PUB_DECODE:EC lib
$ openssl errstr 0x0B07707D
error:0B07707D:x509 certificate routines:X509_PUBKEY_get:public key decode error
$ openssl errstr 0x0906700D
error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib
```

The strange thing is that if i use **exact same** library in C++ code and call it on **exact same** `.pem` file, i get no such error - `EC_KEY` pointer is not `NULL` and no error output from SSL.

There's [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41035) which is the case for my problem, in exception that i wrap OpenSSL in C library and link it via cgo.

I can't wrap my head around why it works like this. Maybe there're some defines that are silently passed upon building (none passed explicitly, go code is built with simple `go build` command), but i couldn't find any info to proceed with this theory.

Comment: Are the two examples run on the same system **and** are both using the same OpenSSL run-time libraries?